# mapbox LineString follow the road

Tags: javascript, dictionary, gps, mapbox

I have a set of GPS locations that I put on a map with mapbox and then draw a line between the points.

Is there a way to draw a smooth/intelligence line that follow the roads? instead of what I got on the drawing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Single marker</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.0.0/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.0.0/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='map'></div>

<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = '<TOKEN_HERE>';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-i86nkdio')
    .setView([40.763656, -73.980603], 15);

L.mapbox.featureLayer({
    // this feature is in the GeoJSON format: see geojson.org
    // for the full specification
    type: 'Feature',
    geometry: {
        type: 'LineString',
        // coordinates here are in longitude, latitude order because
        // x, y is the standard for GeoJSON and many formats
        coordinates:  [
                        [   -73.979552  ,   40.766119   ],
                        [   -73.982556  ,   40.761991   ],
                        [   -73.980399  ,   40.759858   ],
                        [   -73.978575  ,   40.756607   ]
                      ]
    },
    properties: {
        title: 'test',
        description: 'Test',
    }
}).addTo(map);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Image: http://postimg.org/image/x1syq28o5/

Comment: you could try this [LINK](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/dynamically-drawing-a-line/)

Comment: I Don't think I can use that for what.

Answer (score 1):

The line that you've drawn only has the four points you provided. So basically, you need better source data.

Are you trying to do this in a general case or just for this example? The map that you are drawing on is based on OpenStreetMap, so if you could grab that data, you could draw a copy of the road you want on top of the base map.

Comment: I'm trying to do this generally. The example in this question was just to explain the problem. The thing is, if you do it with google maps it will show the correct route.. (The coordinates from the question will show a strange route because the roads in Manhattan are one way, but it works in google maps). So is it possiple to do with mapbox/OSM

Comment: You will need some sort of ability to "snap to roads", which isn't provided in the Mapbox API currently.